# how can i make django password with no Hash algorithm?

Tags: python, django, authentication, passwords

i have made a custom user model in django, and it's OK, working but the problem is that i want to make the password field and auth function with **no hash algorithm**, i know about security problems of that, but that's OK because i won't expose my app in public. because i am working with very old and legacy database data.

custom user model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.utils import timezone


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, name, phone, password, **extra_fields):
        values = [email, name, phone]
        field_value_map = dict(zip(self.model.REQUIRED_FIELDS, values))
        for field_name, value in field_value_map.items():
            if not value:
                raise ValueError('The {} value must be set'.format(field_name))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            name=name,
            phone=phone,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, name, phone, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, name, phone, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, phone, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, name, phone, password, **extra_fields)


class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'phone']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name.split()[0]
```

Comment: You tried modify in your settings.py PASSWORD_HASHERS option?

Comment: "_I am working with very old and legacy database data._" so you have unhashed passwords? What stops you from migrating that data and hashing the users passwords then?

Comment: Yes we have, i know about migrating to hash, but for some reason we cannot do it right now , maybe later